"Lo" versus "il" da Dante
In Nuovi lineamenti di grammatica storica dell'italiano da Giuseppe Patota leggo:

In particolare, nell’italiano antico si aveva lo all’inizio di frase (a) e dopo parola terminante per consonante (b), mentre si aveva il dopo parola terminante per vocale (c). Valgano, in proposito, i seguenti esempi tratti dall'Inferno dantesco:
a) «Lo buon maestro disse: - Figlio, or vedi» (Inf. VII 115);
b) «Non isperate mai veder lo cielo» (ln f III 85);
c) «Poi ch’ei posato un poco il corpo lasso» (lnf. 1 28).
Questo meccanismo distributivo è indicato dai linguisti come norma
Gröber, dal nome dello studioso tedesco che per primo lo individuò nel secolo scorso.

Però nel Canto XVII del Paradiso abbiamo:

Tu proverai sì come sa di sale
lo pane altrui, e come è duro calle
lo scendere e 'l salir per l'altrui scale

Le parole sale e calle terminano con una vocale però abbiamo "lo" dopo queste parole. Sarà che dobbiamo capire che "all’inizio di frase" include "all'inizio di verso"? Altrimenti, come si spiega che abbiamo lo qui e non il?
Ho visto che c'è già una domanda simile però non vedo perché la risposta data lì spieghi che abbiamo lo qui (a meno che dobbiamo capire che "Originally only lo could be used at the beginning of a sentence." include "at the beginning of a verse").

Nell'esempio per «dopo parola terminante per consonante» viene usato «lo cielo» ma «cielo» non termina con una consonante. Inizia con una consonante, come «sale» e «calle». Tutte quelle parole finiscono con una vocale.

Leggendo la risposta data per l'altra domanda, leggo «while lo was used after any ending and before any initial.» che essenzialmente dice che lo era usato indipendentemente dalla prima lettera della parola seguente o dalla sua ultima lettera.

@apaderno Non capisco cosa Lei vuole dire. La parola "veder" termina per consonante, e quindi si aveva "veder lo cielo", non importa che "cielo" inizia con una consonante o finisce con una vocale.

Credo che la risposta semplice consista in una preferenza di Dante per “lo” all'inizio del verso.
La risposta completa consisterebbe nel leggere l'intera voce “il” nell'Enciclopedia dantesca, e in particolare la sezione 2.1, dove tra l'altro si osserva che nei testi poetici di Dante

l'uso di lo è collegato con particolari condizioni contestuali che vigono in tutte le opere di Dante.
In inizio di verso il è generalmente evitato, mentre vi è preferito lo

e segue un'analisi dettagliata dell'uso di “lo” all'inizio di un verso nella Commedia e nelle altre opere. Per esempio (e ricordando anche che a volte i diversi codici presentano versioni diverse):

Nell'Inferno, su 198 attestazioni di lo, 73 ricorrono in inizio di verso [...]; nel Purgatorio 56 su 170 [...]; nel Paradiso 47 su 173 [...]. In inizio di verso il è soltanto in If XXVIII 21 il modo de la nona bolgia sozzo (ma con variante al modo) e 11 volte nel Paradiso

